# Linkedin API - Posting to Pages

Tags: linkedin-api

We have an integration with Linkedin on our site [www.snapsponsorship.com](http://www.snapsponsorship.com) Unfortunately we can only managed to post to users feeds, not to the pages they are associated with. We have this up and running for facebook and have Twitter integrated also. Can I ask is it possible to authenticate a page directly for posting through an API or is it possible to authenticate a users account and then post to a page. Many thanks in advance Regards, Mark

No idea if im posting this is the correct place. apologies if wrong, would appreciate being pointed in the right direction. Im non technical trying to support development team